# What is the difference between print(var,var) and print(var),(var)?

Tags: python

```
**>>>a=2
>>>b=5
>>>print(a,b)
2 5
>>>print(a),(b)
2
(None, 5)**
```

Can someone help me understand why the 2nd print statement returns (None,5)?
I'm new to this, so sorry if this is a silly question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three pertinent facts here.

1. The `print` function returns nothing.  Well, technically it returns "None".  Its usefulness is entirely in its side effects -- printing to the console.
2. The command line interpreter (what you get with ">>>") doesn't print anything if the line returned `None`.  Thus, for `print(a,b)`, you see the  effects of the `print` function, but the return value of the `print` function (`None`) is suppressed.
3. Commas are used to create tuples.  Your third statement creates a two-element tuple.  The first element is the return from `print`, which is `None`.  The second element is the value 5, from the name `b`.  So, on your console, you see the effect of the `print` function (printing `a` which is `2`).  Then, you see the command line interpreter displaying the final result of your statement, which is the tuple `(None, 5)`.

(Actually, "`print` is a function not a statement" is also a pertinent fact...)